# inSSIDer equivalent for Ubuntu with GUI

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

What is a program about the equivalent of inSSIDer or Netstumbler for **Ubuntu 10.04**? Something with a GUI that is easy for Linux beginners to install please.

I tried kismet, but I wouldn't get my card into wireless monitor mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this screenshot it should be coming up pretty soon:

[image]

Comment: any gui for that?

Answer (score 3):

What exactly do you want from this? Are you looking for the channel mapping or the signal strength indication? If the latter, I like [wavemon](http://freshmeat.net/projects/wavemon/)

As several have pointed out, they've been working on a linux version. See [Here](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/linux/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

[Aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php)

They also have a setup guide for linux:
[User Guides](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=user_docs)

If that's too complex (it should do the same things at netstumbler), I would suggest this little program:

[Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/) - Kismet identifies networks by passively collecting packets and detecting standard named networks, detecting (and given time, decloaking) hidden networks, and infering the presence of nonbeaconing networks via data traffic.

Comment: I know what aircrack-ng is, but it is not what I am looking for. I'll give kismet a look though.

Comment: Anything with a GUI??

Comment: Kismet has a simple user interface. It's graphical in some sense, but not in the way we usually think of.

Comment: I like this answer, but I can't get kismet to work with my wireless card

Answer (score 1):

Metageek now has a linux release (alpha) of inSSIDer that works in Ubuntu. http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider

You will probably need the latest Mono release (2.6)